# HTML input with autocomplete but no default value

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have an input element inside a form with the usual browser autocomplete but i don't want the browser to set a default value to it.

The expected behavior would be that the input is always rendered empty and when the user clicks it the browser autocompletes kicks in displaying the previous entered values for that field.

I've seen something similar in [this](http://www.wantworthy.com/login) login page.

I've tried emptying the input values using javascript on page load but it's not a very clean solution as sometimes i can see the default values showing up and then getting erased.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Could it be that you confuse AutoFill with autocomplete? Or are you referring to placeholders?

Comment: Maybe it's a different name. I'm not talking about placeholder. So if you call "AutoFill" the browser feature that set a default value to an input from the saved history then yes, i'm talking about disabling AutoFill.

Comment: `autocomplete="off"` in the form tag could work. Depends on the browser, though.

Comment: But that would disable displaying previous entered values as well.

Comment: Yes, i want autocomplete on but autofill off.

Comment: I fear you will have to turn off autofill in the browser then. Or configure it, if possible. It's a browser feature after all, no web standard.

Comment: But i see exactly this behavior here http://www.wantworthy.com/login. I just can't figure out how their doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wantworthy.com/login creates the page with JavaScript. So when it loads, the input fields are not there and the browser can't fill them.

If you don't want to go so far you could only create the input fields after the page has loaded. Maybe something even simpler like changing the names of the fields could to the trick (Fake names before, real names after the page has loaded). But you have to figure out when the browser fills the fields: onDocumentReady, onLoad or even later.

As written in the comments you can use `autocomplete="off"` in the form tag if you want no browser intervention at all. But that would turn off displaying previously entered values as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be your answer...
http://liveweave.com/dnEfCD

Just use the 'placeholder' attribute.

```
 <form id="main">
<input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
 </form>
```

Comment: That's not the issue. I'm already using placeholder. Again, i just want to force the browser to show the placeholder instead of autofilling the input with some value from the browser history.